# Lidar - What is the difference between the /scan and PointCloud?

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I watched a tutorial for converting laser scan data to point cloud.

But I could not understand how this conversion works.

What is the difference between the scan and point-cloud data and what are these codes doing?
The tutorials were not in detail for theoretical parts and everything I could read was just focused on the results.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400854/lidar---what-is-the-difference-between-the-/scan-and-pointcloud?/) by [kiru](https://answers.ros.org/users/97217/kiru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-05-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I hope I'll be able to explain it enough.

First, I think it's important to look at the [LaserScan message](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html). The first part after the header gives you the min and max angle + the distance between each measurement.

So imagine a circle with a midpoint. The midpoint is your `lidar_link` so it has a 'front' (the direction of the x axis). The front is your 0 rad.

If you have a `min_angle` of pi (-90 degrees, I'm going to stick with degrees from here on, but it's actually rads) you know where to start. Your `float32[] ranges` is a list of ranges. The first range is at -90 degrees. If your `angle_increment` is 1 degree, then the second range is at -89 the third at -88 etc.

That's kinda like one of those [hand fans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_fan) where each of the blades is 1 range.

In a way, that means the `LaserScan` message is not really 2D. It's a list of 1D lengths that you make 2D by plotting them out on a circle.

Now for pointclouds. If somebody has more experience with them, please correct me. However, I have always understood it as being an actual 2(or3)D pointcloud.

Looking back at the `lidar_link` (or `pointcloud_link` if you will), it doesn't just have a 'front'. It has an x, y and z axis. It is a 3D origin. If you have a point `(2, 0, 1)` that's a point 2 meter in front of the link and 1 meter up. A pointcloud uses a grid to express each point.

Now for the final part of your question, how the conversion works. If you've got a lidar message, basically have vectors with a magnitude and length (hopefully [khanacademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:vectors/x9e81a4f98389efdf:component-form/a/vector-magnitude-and-direction-review) helps explaining what I mean). In the link I posted, they went from a point (a,b) to a magnitude and direction. However, for a lidar to pointcloud conversion you would of course do the opposite. You go from a magnitude and direction to a coordinate.

I hope this helped you a bit with understanding the difference.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-19**:
A good summary I've always found is that a laser scan is essentially a set of points in a polar coordinate system (length and direction), while a point cloud stores points in a Cartesian coordinate system.

Conceptually, there is also the difference that a laser scan is the result of a radial measurement (ie: single sensor in the middle), while a point cloud is typically the result of many sensors in parallel (ie: line or square of sensors).

This implies a laser scan also typically is not composed of measurements measured at the *same time*, but the first point will be captured at an earlier time than the last (and this can be a significant amount of time).

The points in a point cloud are typically considered to be captured all at the same time (there is often a non-zero delta-t between the first and last points, but it's (considered) negligible with many sensors).

Of course: conversions between laser scans and pointclouds exist, but you lose the above semantics a bit.